# Android sendBroadcast inside broadcast breaks app

Tags: java, android, crash, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have a `BroadcastListener` that checkes for incomning textmessages and process them to get the potential status of the alarm system.

If the text matched my criteria and the activity of my app in the foreground, I want to show the status in the GUI of my activity.

For this I try to use an intent like this:

```
public class SmsReader extends BroadcastReceiver implements Runnable
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "SMSReceiver";
    private String alarm = "15555215554";

    public static final String INCOMING_SMS_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    public static final String ALARM_STATUS_ON_FULL = "moorehojer.alarmcontrol.intent.action.ALARM_STATUS_FULL_ON";
    public static final String ALARM_STATUS_ON_PART = "moorehojer.alarmcontrol.intent.action.ALARM_STATUS_PART_ON";
    public static final String ALARM_STATUS_OFF = "moorehojer.alarmcontrol.intent.action.ALARM_STATUS_OFF";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent intent) 
    {
        String intentActionToCall = "";

        if (intent.getAction().equals(INCOMING_SMS_ACTION)) 
        {
            //this stops notifications to others
            this.abortBroadcast();
            boolean releaseBroadcast = false;

            try
            {   
                Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
                SmsMessage [] messages = null;

                if (myBundle != null)
                {
                    Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
                    messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
                    {
                        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                            if(!Util.UnifyPhoneNumberPrefix(messages[i].getOriginatingAddress()).equals(Util.UnifyPhoneNumberPrefix(this.alarm)))
                        {
                            releaseBroadcast = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(messages[i].getMessageBody().substring(0, 5).equals("FS-C "))
                            {
                                boolean frakoblet01 = messages[i].getMessageBody().contains("FRAKOBLET1");
                                boolean frakoblet02 = messages[i].getMessageBody().contains("FRAKOBLET2");
                                boolean tilkoblet01 = messages[i].getMessageBody().contains("TILKOBLET1");
                                boolean tilkoblet02 = messages[i].getMessageBody().contains("TILKOBLET2");
                                boolean deltilkoblet01 = messages[i].getMessageBody().contains("DELTILKOBLET1");
                                boolean deltilkoblet02 = messages[i].getMessageBody().contains("DELTILKOBLET2");

                                if(deltilkoblet01 || deltilkoblet02)
                                {
                                    intentActionToCall = SmsReader.ALARM_STATUS_ON_PART;
                                }
                                else if(tilkoblet01 && tilkoblet02)
                                {
                                    intentActionToCall = SmsReader.ALARM_STATUS_ON_FULL;
                                }
                                else if(frakoblet01 && frakoblet02)
                                {
                                    intentActionToCall = SmsReader.ALARM_STATUS_OFF;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    releaseBroadcast = true;    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                this.makeToast(_context, "Ex 1: "+e.toString());
            }
            /**/

            try 
            {
                if(releaseBroadcast)
                {
                    this.clearAbortBroadcast();
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                this.makeToast(_context, e.toString());
            }
        } 

        if(!intentActionToCall.equals(""))
        {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(intentActionToCall);

                this.makeToast(_context, "Intent created:\n"+intentActionToCall);

                    this.makeToast(_context, "Trying broadcast");
                    myIntent.putExtra("message", "Hallelujah");
                    try
                    {
                        _context.sendBroadcast(myIntent);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
    }

    private void makeToast(Context context, String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

But everytime the code reach the line:

```
_context.sendBroadcast(myIntent);
```

The OS comes up with a message that the process has stopped working unexpectingly and is shutdown with the try-catch stepping in.

I've tried removing the line and the code runs to the end without problems.

Comment: Could you please post the logcat backtrace?

Comment: how do I acces that (emulator)

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html please